# Users timeline help claims to be pageable but isn't

Tags: bug, status-completed

The help page for the users timeline call claims that the timeline can handle paging but it doesn't seem to be able to. The output doesn't have the total count of pages, etc and the page attribute doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

`/users/{id}/timeline` now honors the `page` and `pagesize` parameters.  `sort`, `order`, `min`, and `max have been removed.

The expected "wrapper" fields (`total`, `page`, and `pagesize`) are now returned as well.

Comment: Are `questions/{id}/timeline` results also supposed to be wrapped in a page?

Comment: @ColinD - they are now.

Answer (score 0):

For that matter, it claims to accept `sort`, `order`, `min` and `max` but it doesn't seem to... they seem to just be the same as for `/users`.

`/questions/{id}/timeline` also has `page` and `pagesize` parameters, but I'm guessing they shouldn't be there since the result isn't in the page format.